# Can't create a new view

Tags: views, 7

I am having trouble creating a new View. I am just testing out the module, but when I click "Save" after setting everything up, I receive the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of
>   collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   for operation '=': SELECT s.uid, c.updated FROM {ctools_object_cache}
>   c INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON c.sid = s.sid WHERE s.sid <> :session_id
>   AND c.obj = :obj AND c.name = :name ORDER BY c.updated ASC; Array (
>   [:session_id] => 3nTvCCvx2_Zopg07JqIBReKxL3TzvilIkwmHjFKZ93o [:obj] =>
>   view [:name] => recently_posted_jobs ) in ctools_object_cache_test()
>   (line 145 of
>   /home1/mt/public_html/mtnet/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/object-cache.inc).
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all your caches and try again.

You db seems to become corrupted or misconfigured. Your ctools module is using a different collation to store values in the db. So most of your site is utf8_general_ci and the ctools is using utf8_unicode_ci.

I gathered all of that from this line:

> (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=': SELECT s.uid, c.updated FROM {ctools_object_cache}

---

If the clearing of caches fails then...

If you have phpmyadmin installed, go to the site's db and check what the Collate value is. Try changing it to utf_8 or something.

---

**NOTE: I would create a backup of the db before you play with any collate value stuff.**

Comment: I followed your advice, and it worked! For posterity, I changed the "Collation" field for the ctools_css_cache, ctools_custom_content, and ctools_object_cache tables in my database to utf8_unicode_ci. Make sure the Collation value is the same for all tables in your database, otherwise you'll experience the same issues I did. So it doesn't have to be "utf8_unicode_ci", that's just what the Collation value was for all of the other tables in my DB, so it's what I settled on. As long as there's consistency, you'll be good!